# How to deploy Visual Studio Package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vspackage

I've written a Visual Studio 2010 Package (VSPackage) that is an improved version of the "Task List". We plan to use this at the office for more or less day to day operations, it's exceptionally easy to use since its persistent storage is the code where you write the tags.

So far so good.

Does anyone have a tutorial on how to produce an MSI package to deploy a VSPackage like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN works well in this case, read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb458038%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and focus on "Deployment By Using a Setup Project".

Comment: Consider summarising the article and posting it here.  _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_.  Also, as of the time of writing, _Setup Projects_ are **not** a feature of VS2012+